# Excel VBA Macro Find and Format

Tags: excel, vba, find, format

I am trying to create a macro that can find a particular string in a header, then format the cells in that column.  For an example, I have a header called "Purchase Date", "Cap Date", and "Exp Date".  I want to be able to find the first instance of "Date" used, format them as text, then find the next occurance and format, etc.

I have created one that will find only the first instance, then not look for any further.  Any idea?  I have looked up "Find" and "After", but cannot get them to function correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: _I have created one that will find only the first instance_ - then post your code!

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled moving past the first find. ook at the last part fo the code below from Do While.  Maybe you can work something from it.

```
Sub HyperLinking()     
  Call HyperLink("Text TO Hyperlink", "C:\Document.docx")   
End Sub 

Private Function HyperLink(LinkName As String, LinkAddress As String) 
  Dim WDApp As Object, wd As Object, rn As Long 
  On Error Resume Next 
  Set WDApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then 
      Set WDApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
  End If 
  On Error Goto 0 
  Set wd = WDApp.Documents.Open(LinkAddress) 
  WDApp.Visible = True 
  Set objWdRange = wd.Content      
  objWdRange.Find.ClearFormatting 
  With objWdRange.Find 
      .Text = LinkName 
      .Forward = True 
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue 
  End With 
  Do While objWdRange.Find.Execute = True 
      objWdRange.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=objWdRange, Address:=LinkAddress, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="Linked  Document", TextToDisplay:=LinkName 
      objWdRange.Find.Execute 
  Loop      
  wd.Save 
  wd.Close 
  Set wd = Nothing 
  Set WDApp = Nothing      
End Function
```

One problem is that sometimes, I guess due to formatting, all the words are not found.  Maybe someone can help with why this happens?

You can adapt this code to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly elegant, but this will most likely do the trick for you.  Just edit some of the hardcoded values like sheetname and make sure that you don't have more than 99 columns or 999 rows.

```vb
Public Sub FormatRowsInDateColumns()
Dim header As String

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

'loop through columns
For col = 1 To 99

    'check if header cell contains word date
    header = Cells(1, col).Value
    If InStr(1, header, "date", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

        'convert cell values to string
        For Row = 1 To 999
            'Formats value and perserves as text with an apostrophe
            Cells(Row, col).Value = "'" & Format(Cells(Row, col).Value, "yyyy/mm/dd")
        Next Row

        'set column format as text
        Columns(col).NumberFormat = "@"
    End If
Next col

End Sub
```